# How do I use my existing G Suite apps inside Squarespace?

Tags: wordpress, squarespace, google-workspace, velo, weebly

I am paying for a G Suite business plan. I have a domain, host, and emails set up already, and would like to use the G Suite apps inside my website builder (Squarespace).

But Squarespace does not let me do this without signing up to a new G Suite account through their platform. Their exact words are, "If you have G Suite through Google or another reseller, it isn't possible to link it to your Squarespace site".

So I tried looking at Google's other website builder partners like WordPress, Wix and Weebly for example. They all say the same thing.

WordPress: "If you would like to transfer your G Suite account to WordPress.com (G Suite Reseller), then this is unfortunately not possible at the moment"

WIX: "Currently, transferring your existing G Suite Account to Wix is not supported".

I could not find any documentation telling me that Weebly supports the transfer either.

All I want to do, is use the G Suite apps on my site without having to delete my current G Suite account and sign up to a new one. I have already paid the money for the subscription for my existing G Suite.

If I deleted my existing G Suite and signed up with a new G Suite account through the website builder, I'd have to delete the domain name, wait until it is available again, then re-purchase it. Essentially spending twice the money. I'd also have to figure out what to do with my emails because I read that after you delete them, you can't re-create  them. I'm sure I could migrate them over somehow but what a hassle. I have also paid for business cards that I'd have to re-print as well. I don't want to go down that pathway.

Surely you can use your G Suite account with a new website. Surely. But how?

And I'm not talking about just transfering the domain over, or chaning the MX records so I can use my email... I'm talking about everything. Integrating calendar for example in the website, using the files in google drive, basically managing everything through the website builder as if I had originally created the G Suite account in the website builder to begin with.

Is there anyone that can help me figure out a solution? I can't find information on this anywhere, I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

I should also mention I am very new to G Suite and website builders.

Answer (score 0):

You got your answer.. "If you have G Suite through Google or another reseller, it isn't possible to link it to your Squarespace site". I'm sure most platforms/resellers work this way.

Aside from deleting the account, and waiting, using 'embeddable code' on you website, like [Add a Google calendar to your website](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207) is about your only option.